# Metro App are not installaling (side loading) in Windows 8 when the simulator is running

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, side-loading

When I am trying to install any metro app using side loading it will not install if I also have the simulator running (Visual Studio 2012) on same pc.

If I close the simulator, the app installs correctly.

Is there any way around this in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that my app is targeted to local mechine in release type in Visula Studio.
If i changed the mouse focus from simulator which is running on desktop, the app is installed.
In other hand i have installed my app which is release type changed to simulator and it is installed when mouse focus is on simulator.